# Can I query MYSQL for a specific datatype?

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, sqldatatypes

Can I query a MYSQL database for what tables use a specific datatype?

For example: We are wanting to use CakeDC migrations (For CakePHP) which do not support database specific features such as enums. How would I get a comprehensive list of which tables use enums so we can get an idea of how our system might be affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'enum';
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I knew it was in information_schema somewhere :)